# Update mysql Row with value from SQLite on android studio

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to make an android app that's when internet connection is turned on it will updating the data at the server with the value from my local SQLite database

This is my Activity Code.

```
public class SyncCollectActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private CollectDataHelper dbHelper;
private ListView list;
private List<SyncCollect> syncs;
Cursor cursor;

public static final int NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 1;
public static final int NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 0;
public static final String DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST = "id.habatus.datasaved";

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
private SyncCollectAdapter adapter;
Button col, drop;
ImageButton back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync_collect);
    dbHelper = new CollectDataHelper(this);
    syncs = new ArrayList<>();

    list = findViewById(R.id.listViewNames);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    drop = findViewById(R.id.btncanvas);
    back = findViewById(R.id.kembali);
    loadData();
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //loading the names again
            loadData();
            refresh();

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));


    drop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SyncCollectActivity.this,SyncActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SyncCollectActivity.this,DecisionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

private void loadData() {
    syncs.clear();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            SyncCollect sync = new SyncCollect(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_p")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nama")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alamat")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("saldo")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pinjaman")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("angsuran")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("keterangan")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("latitude")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("longitude")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status")),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CollectDataHelper.syncstatus))

            );
            syncs.add(sync);
        }
    }
    adapter = new SyncCollectAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(),R.layout.sync_item2,syncs);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void refresh(){
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}
}
```

This is my URL.

```
public static final String URL_COL_SYNC = "http://192.168.4.9/SqliteSync/colsync.php?id_p=";
```

This class is where my method to update the data from my SQLite database to server.

```
public class NetworkCollect  extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Context context;
private CollectDataHelper db;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    db = new CollectDataHelper(context);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null){
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            Cursor cursor = db.getUnsynced();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    save(

                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.nama)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.alamat)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.saldo)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.pinjaman)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.angsuran)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.keterangan)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.latitude)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.longitude)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.status)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.id_p))
                    );
                }

        }
    }
}

private void save( final String nama, final String alamat,final String saldo,final String pinjaman,
                  final String angsuran, final String keterangan,final String latitude,final String longitude,final String status,final String id_p){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Konfigurasi.URL_COL_SYNC, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    //updating the status in sqlite
                    db.updatelocal(id_p, SyncCollectActivity.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);

                    //sending the broadcast to refresh the list
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(SyncCollectActivity.DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> Params = new HashMap<>();
            Params.put("nama",nama);
            Params.put("alamat",alamat);
            Params.put("saldo",saldo);
            Params.put("pinjaman",pinjaman);
            Params.put("angsuran",angsuran);
            Params.put("keterangan",keterangan);
            Params.put("latitude",latitude);
            Params.put("longitude",longitude);
            Params.put("status",status);
            Params.put("id_p",id_p);
            return Params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}

}
```

and this is my php code to update the server data.

```
    <?php 
/*
* Database Constants
* Make sure you are putting the values according to your database here 
*/
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_NAME', 'user');

//Connecting to the database
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

//checking the successful connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//making an array to store the response
$response = array(); 

//if there is a post request move ahead 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 //getting the name from request 
 $id_p = $_POST['id_p'];
$nama =$_POST['nama'];
$alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
$saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
$pinjaman = $_POST['pinjaman'];
$angsuran = $_POST['angsuran'];
$keterangan = $_POST['keterangan'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
//creating a statement to insert to database 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE collect SET nama=?, alamat=?, saldo=?, pinjaman=?, angsuran=?, keterangan=?, latitude=?, longitude=?, status=?, WHERE id_p=?");

 //binding the parameter to statement 
 $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $nama,$alamat,$saldo,$pinjaman,$angsuran,$keterangan,$latitude,$longitude,$status,$id_p);

 //if data inserts successfully
 if($stmt->execute()){
 //making success response 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'Saved successfully'; 
 }else{
 //if not making failure response 
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = 'Please try later';
 }

}else{
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = "Invalid request"; 
}

//displaying the data in json format 
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

In my php code I use a prepared statement for updating the data to server.

I make this based on a tutorial at a website but that's for insert and i want to make it not insert but update. i've tried to use intent.putextra to the broadcastreceiver but the save method at NetworkCollect class doesn't work. and the worse is there's no exception. Maybe anyone can help?

I hope someone can help me find the solution.

Thank You very much.

Comment: "Its not working" doesnt tell us much! What doesnt work? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: the doesn't work is the save method on networkcollect, i've tried to use intent.putextra but it's change nothing

Comment: share what exception is coming here for better understanding of Why it is not working?

Comment: well there is no exception, that's why i am confused, i've already edit my question

Comment: can anyone help me?